# Nodejs app EC2 t2micro is faster than my local machine when comparing the network response time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, performance, rest, amazon-ec2

I am not able to understand why this is happening can anyone tell me why this could be happening?

4 seconds on my local machine
[image: local]

under 1 second from ec2
[image: ec2]

Comment: Your network is slow?

Comment: No, if my network is slow both the application should respond slow right? @John Rotenstein

Comment: Your screenshots suggest to me that you are measuring the time taken to download a particular file in your web browser request. From where is the file being served? Is it from the same computer, or from a different computer on the Internet?

Comment: it is from my local machine @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Does the first picture represent downloading a file from your own computer TO your own computer? Taking 4 seconds to do that sounds rather excessive.

Comment: In that case, you would receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com